# Exception occured while initialize the Xconnect config

Tags: xdb, xconnect

I have a requirement to create contact and push into XDB using Xconnect.So I'm referring to the [blog](https://citizensitecore.com/2017/10/17/xconnect-creating-contacts-in-sitecore-9/) for my implementation

So when I'm trying to initialize the Xconnect config. It is throwing an exception.

**Code Snippet**

```
 private static XConnectClient GetClient()
    {
        var config = new XConnectClientConfiguration(
           new XdbRuntimeModel(CollectionModel.Model),
           new Uri("https://site.xconnect/"),
           new Uri("https://site.xconnect/"));
        try
        {
            config.Initialize();
        }
        catch (XdbModelConflictException ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            throw;
        }

        return new XConnectClient(config);
    }
```

I'm getting following exception while calling the  **config.Initialize();** as shown below:

**The HTTP response was not successful: Unauthorized**

I have referred below [Post](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8561/xconnect-the-http-response-was-not-successful-unauthorized) but no luck. My scenario is something different as compared with the question.

Please see below snapshot for the exact error information.

[image]

Please see below for stack trace of the error:

> at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
>      at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.Initialize(XConnectClientConfiguration config)
>      at CreateContact.Program.GetClient() in D:\POC\XconnectPOC\CreateContact\Program.cs:line 65
>      at CreateContact.Program.AddContact() in D:\POC\XconnectPOC\CreateContact\Program.cs:line 23
>      at CreateContact.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Lexus\POC\XconnectPOC\CreateContact\Program.cs:line 17
>      at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
>      at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass correct certificate on the following line:

> CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifierOptions.Parse("StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=15E6693B0AECB63DE57D991EC363CA462DC52432");

Please try this code:

```
// Valid certificate thumbprints must be passed in
 CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifierOptions options =
 CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifierOptions.Parse("StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=15E6693B0AECB63DE57D991EC363CA462DC52432");

 // Optional timeout modifier
 var certificateModifier = new CertificateWebRequestHandlerModifier(options);
 List<IHttpClientModifier> clientModifiers = new List<IHttpClientModifier>();
 var timeoutClientModifier = new TimeoutHttpClientModifier(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20));

 clientModifiers.Add(timeoutClientModifier);

 // This overload takes three client end points - collection, search, and configuration
 var collectionClient = new CollectionWebApiClient(new Uri("https://sc900rev170622_xconnect/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
 var searchClient = new SearchWebApiClient(new Uri("https://sc900rev170622_xconnect/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
 var configurationClient = new ConfigurationWebApiClient(new Uri("https://sc900rev170622_xconnect/configuration"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });

 var cfg = new XConnectClientConfiguration(
                new XdbRuntimeModel(CollectionModel.Model), collectionClient, searchClient, configurationClient);
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have changed the code accordingly. But I'm getting below error now.  

{"The HTTP response was not successful: Forbidden"}

Comment: did you modify Thumbprint value?

Comment: when you access xconnect from browser what do you see?

Comment: I have changed the thumbprint value and I see below while accessing the Xconnect from browser. I can see below response.
"0:06:22.5098385"

Comment: It should work now; did you change on my code urls to your xconnect urls

Comment: Yeah, I did the changes as you have mentioned
`var collectionClient = new CollectionWebApiClient(new Uri("https://sites.xconnect/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
            var searchClient = new SearchWebApiClient(new Uri("https://sites.xconnect/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
            var configurationClient = new ConfigurationWebApiClient(new Uri("https://sites.xconnect/configuration"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });`

But while browsing those URL's.I'm getting blank page of /ODATA linka and 404 for /Configuration

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? If yes, please let me know what you did.