# xConnect error - The OnlineInteractions graph cannot be displayed due to a server error

Tags: xconnect

After installation of Sitecore 9 we were able to get the xConnect working by performing the below steps

1. Have executed the post installation script
2. Installed both xConnect & xConnect.Client certificate in both Personal & Trusted root path of Current User as well as local computer
3. Have updated the thumbprint in Xconnect App.Config & also added the below Connection String

Post which we were able to initialize/interact with xConnect successfully, however this breaks the Marketing Analytics page in sitecore with the below error.

There are more Errors:
•   The OnlineInteractions graph cannot be displayed due to a server error. Contact you system administrator.
•   The ChannelsByVisits graph cannot be displayed due to a server error. Contact you system administrator.
•   The TopTenCampaignsByValue graph cannot be displayed due to a server error. Contact you system administrator.
•   The TopTenPatternsByValuePerVisit graph cannot be displayed due to a server error. Contact you system administrator.
•   The TopTenGoalsByConversions graph cannot be displayed due to a server error. Contact you system administrator.
•   The OnlineInteractionsByVisitsAndValuePerVisit graph cannot be displayed due to a server error. Contact you system administrator.

Request technical guidance to get both xConnect & Marketing Analytics up and running.

Comment: Are you able to provide the detailed errors from the Sitecore logs? Have you contacted Sitecore support yet?

Comment: I've seen this before and it was the certificate.  Make sure that the xconnect client certificate is working.  Did you update the connection strings in your Sitecore website with the thumbprint also?

Comment: @Marco:Yes, i have already updated the XConnect connection string in my web.config and also installed both XConnect & Xconnect.Client certificate in both Personal & Trusted root path of Current User as well as local computer.

Comment: Maybe this would help https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8561/xconnect-the-http-response-was-not-successful-unauthorized?rq=1

Comment: I have also seen this before and it was a bad Request Verification Token. Clear your client cookies and try again.

Comment: Got it Resolved. The problem was that, when i reinstalled SSL certificate, it was missing the required permission.
With clean instance, for the certificate i had given permission to Administrator, IIS-users & also to my local account. Post which I was able to get both XConnect and Experience analytics graph working.
Reference Link: https://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/10/All-about-xConnect-Security/

Comment: Check the logs of your Sitecore Reporting and various xConnect instances. They will reveal the issues. In my case I had a typo in ConnectionStrings.config.

Answer (score 0):

Got it Resolved. The problem was that, when i reinstalled SSL certificate, it was missing the required permission. With clean instance, for the certificate i had given permission to Administrator, IIS-users & also to my local account. Post which I was able to get both XConnect and Experience analytics graph working. Reference Link: http://kamsar.net/index.php/2017/10/All-about-xConnect-Security