# Graphs in Experience Analytics cannot be displayed

Tags: xconnect, experience-analytics

I installed Sitecore 9.1 using Powershell scripts and site is loading fine. All Content Editor related things are working fine. Also, installed both xConnect & xConnect.Client certificate in both Personal & Trusted root path of Current User as well as local computer. I see Xconnect site loading fine as expected.

Now when I try to open Experience Analytics it is showing below set of errors:

- The OnlineInteractions graph cannot be displayed due to a server
  error. Contact you system administrator.
- The ChannelsByVisits graph cannot be displayed due to a server
  error. Contact you system administrator.
- The TopTenCampaignsByValue graph cannot be displayed due to a
  server error. Contact you system administrator.
- The TopTenPatternsByValuePerVisit graph cannot be displayed due to
  a server error. Contact you system administrator.
- The TopTenGoalsByConversions graph cannot be displayed due to a server
  error. Contact you system administrator.
- The OnlineInteractionsByVisitsAndValuePerVisit graph cannot be displayed
  due to a server error. Contact you system administrator.

Also Below is the stack trace -

```
18624 22:48:22 ERROR [Sitecore Services]: HTTP GET
URL http://sitecore9xpo/sitecore/api/ao/aggregates/all/56649EAC3CCF4EAB88B0C74862DB862B/all?&dateGrouping=by-auto&&keyOrderBy=visits-Desc&dateFrom=20-11-2018&dateTo=17-02-2019&keyGrouping=by-key

Exception System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: Unable to connect to the remote server ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 172.22.218.218:8085
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.InternalEndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.EndConnect(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Net.ServicePoint.ConnectSocketInternal(Boolean connectFailure, Socket s4, Socket s6, Socket& socket, IPAddress& address, ConnectSocketState state, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Exception& exception)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetRequestStream(IAsyncResult asyncResult, TransportContext& context)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetRequestStreamCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.Get(IEnumerable`1 keys, NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetReportSegments()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.RequestTypeResolver.GetRequestType()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.GetModelFromBindingContext(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Api.Http.ModelBinding.ReportQueryModelBinder.BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
   at System.Web.Http.ModelBinding.ModelBinderParameterBinding.ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionBinding.<ExecuteBindingAsyncCore>d__12.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__6.MoveNext()
```

Please help me out here to solve the issue. Thanks in Advance.

Regards
Rajath

Comment: Have you deployed marketing definitions?

Comment: No, i have not defined marketing definations till now. Since i am getting error in Experince Analytics Dashbord, i am trying to solve the same.

Comment: I mean have you done this https://doc.sitecore.com/users/82/sitecore-experience-platform/en/deploy-marketing-definitions-and-taxonomies.html#UUID-9faa9232-bff2-3a6b-4a9a-30f4d319be3f_id__Deploy_all_marketing_body

Comment: Hi Mark, Nope i am getting below exception in logs when try to deploy marketing definations. Also i have not configured Configure Session State Providers. 24672 00:36:01 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/aggregator
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web Nested Exception

Exception: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: mscorlib

Comment: Ok so that is your real issue. Experience analytics not working is a side effect of this issue. Please see https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/8561/1278

Answer (score 0):

Can you Check the below areas:

1. Your xconnect site should have a proper Certificate.
2. Ensure that your xconnect site is running in the HTTPS Protocol.
3. Make sure that your xconnect services are running(`sitecorexconnect-Indexworker`,`sitecorexconnect-MarketingAutomationservice`). if those services are in a running state, then try to restart the services.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).