# Sitecore Azure PaaS Client Certificate on ASE

Tags: sitecore-client, xconnect, azure, paas

I deployed Sitecore 9.2 on Azure PaaS and facing the issue with Client Certificate Authentication. The Azure hosting is on ASE with Isolated App Service Plan.

It seems like CM server is not able to communicate with the xConnect services. I have verified the client certificate thumbprint on all the roles and also append AllowInvalidClientCertificates=true to the connection strings since I am using self signed certificate. However issue still persists.

There is similar question 
sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/17013/1278 however the answer are already implemented in my solution but it doesn't resolve the problem I am facing.

[image: Experience Analytics Dashboard]

[image: Network from Developers tool]

Any suggestions to resolve the issue?

Comment: Please see answers on https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/q/17013/1278

Comment: Thanks Mark, I have edited my question again. The answers mentioned in the link is already in place as part of Sitecore ARM template execution.

Comment: Assuming you have a XP scaled topology, can you check at your xConnect Search ConnectionStrings.config under App_Data\jobs\continuous\IndexWorker\App_Config and see if the URL pointing to your collection.search / solrCore is correct?

Comment: @ViniciusDeschamps I am using Azure Search and url is pointing to correct index 
```https://site-as.search.windows.net;indexName=xdb;apiKey=XXX```

Comment: And have you check the Network Security Group of your App Service Isolated and check if the communication happens between the Sitecore roles?

Answer (score 2):

I was able to resolve the issue by following the article https://www.patrickob.com/2018/11/10/adding-ca-certs-to-the-trusted-root-store-for-web-apps-hosted-in-an-ase/

Basically I had to import the all the certificates in chain and add it to the trusted root. This was only required since we are internally signed certificate.