# Unable to load Experience Analytics

Tags: xdb, xconnect

Experience Analytics is not loading. I have checked the following :-

1. Able to load xConnect with out any problem with valid certificate.
2. Thumbprint is updated is xconnect website, connectionstring and appsettings
   and also connectionstring in the sc website
3. Moved trusted root certificates to CA.
4. Rebooted machine.
5. Done post installation steps of Sitecore installation.

I have attached the screenshots and logs. Not sure what else needs to be checked. Please let me know if you need any more information from my side.

```
23324 08:21:58 FATAL [Experience Analytics]: Failed to synchronize segments. Message: Ensure definition type did not complete successfully. StatusCode: 401, ReasonPhrase: 'Invalid certificate', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Pragma: no-cache
  Cache-Control: no-cache
  Date: Thu, 26 Sep 2019 12:21:58 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 0
  Expires: -1
}. Details:    at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Core.Repositories.ReferenceData.ReferenceDataSegmentReader.GetAll(NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Aggregation.Repositories.AggregationSegmentReader.GetAll(NameValueCollection readingPreferences)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SyncSegmentsManager.GetSegmentsToSynchronize()
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SyncSegmentsManager.SynchronizeAllSegments()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.ExperienceAnalytics.Client.Deployment.SyncSegmentsProcessor.<Process>d__4.MoveNext()
ManagedPoolThread #0 08:21:58 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #1 08:21:59 INFO  Trying to load XML configuration /App_Config/Security/GlobalRoles.config
23136 08:22:00 INFO  Cache created: 'ExperienceAnalytics.Sites' (max size: 1MB, running total: 3446MB)
23136 08:22:00 INFO  Cache created: 'ReportingStorageProviderProperties.Properties' (max size: 10MB, running total: 3456MB)
13616 08:22:00 INFO  Cache created: 'Task Manager - Tasks' (max size: 100 bytes, running total: 3456MB)
20108 08:22:02 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgent
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: The HTTP response was not successful: Unauthorized
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

22240 08:22:06 INFO  Cache created: 'SqlDataProvider - Prefetch data(core)' (max size: 150MB, running total: 3606MB)
ManagedPoolThread #0 08:22:06 INFO  Loading Dictionary from cache
ManagedPoolThread #0 08:22:06 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
22240 08:22:07 INFO  Cache created: 'scripts' (max size: 800KB, running total: 3607MB)
22240 08:22:07 WARN  Request is redirected to login page. Requested url: /sitecore/client/Applications/ExperienceAnalytics/Dashboard/, User: sitecore\Anonymous, Website: shell
21728 08:22:08 INFO  HttpModule is being initialized
2204 08:22:15 INFO  Cache created: 'Task Manager - Tasks' (max size: 100 bytes, running total: 3607MB)
ManagedPoolThread #2 08:22:17 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 08:22:17 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
20108 08:22:17 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgent
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: The HTTP response was not successful: Unauthorized
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

ManagedPoolThread #3 08:22:27 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #3 08:22:27 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
23136 08:22:30 INFO  Cache created: 'ExperienceAnalytics.Sites' (max size: 1MB, running total: 3608MB)
ManagedPoolThread #0 08:22:31 ERROR Exception in alarm clock event subscriber.
Exception: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException
Message: Binary stream '0' does not contain a valid BinaryHeader. Possible causes are invalid stream or object version change between serialization and deserialization.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Data.DataAccess.SubmitQueue.FileSubmitQueue.Dequeue()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.SubmitQueueService.WakeUp()
   at Sitecore.Services.AlarmClock.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<Heartbeat_Beat>b__0(Object state)

20108 08:22:32 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgent
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: The HTTP response was not successful: Unauthorized
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

ManagedPoolThread #2 08:22:37 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 08:22:37 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #3 08:22:47 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #3 08:22:47 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
21460 08:22:47 INFO  [Path Analyzer](.) Map EnsureAllDeployed started.
22712 08:22:47 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerHistoryAgent
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: The HTTP response was not successful: Unauthorized
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

20108 08:22:48 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerLiveAgent
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: The HTTP response was not successful: Unauthorized
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Have u verified thumbprints in jobs folder of xConnect for both the services?

Comment: Hi Sumit, thank you for your response.
yes thumbprint is correct in  \App_data\jobs\continuous\AutomationEngine\App_Config\ ConnectionStrings.config.

Comment: I got this same error, came to know certificate was expired. Once certificate was updated, Analytics started working. The exception message also shows `ReasonPhrase: 'Invalid certificate`. Can you check your certificate?

Comment: Hi Madhu, thank you. are you referring to certificate validity(from&to) , if so my certificate is valid till 2/5/2020.  i have attached screenshot of certificate to the original post.

Answer (score 1):

### Things to try

#### App pool user

Did you change your app pool identity? If so, you need to give your app pool user access to the xconnect certificate.

[image]

#### Thumb print difference

In your Sitecore website connectionstrings.config, note the `xconnect.collection.certificate`

```
<add name="xconnect.collection.certificate" connectionString="StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=DC7E10DC79E4BA82B5464BA6D56EED3F11CE7692" />
```

In your xConnect /App_Config/AppSettings.config compare the thumbprint

```
<add key="validateCertificateThumbprint" value="DC7E10DC79E4BA82B5464BA6D56EED3F11CE7692" />
```

#### SSL issue

Open you xConnect site in a browser. Does it produce an SSL cert issue? (I.e. open https://sc910.xconnect/). You should see a date time format number and no ssl issues.

[image]

Also see this thread: [xConnect The HTTP response was not successful: Unauthorized](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8561/xconnect-the-http-response-was-not-successful-unauthorized)