# XDB: An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DeviceProfilesController'

Tags: xconnect

Using Sitecore 9.2 and SXA, XDB is giving us this error in the logs and is not recording data. XDB is enabled and the xconnect default.aspx page is viewable in a browser.  Any ideas?

```
Message: xDB unavailable
Source: Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.XConnectDataAdapterProvider.ExecuteWithExceptionHandling[T](Func`2 func)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounters.OperationPerformanceMonitorExtensions.Monitor[T](OperationPerformanceMonitorBase monitor, Func`1 operation)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.XConnect.DataAccess.Dictionaries.XConnectDeviceDictionary.LoadAs[T](Object key)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.AverageCounterExtensions.MeasureMilliseconds[T](AverageCounter counter, Func`1 func)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.DataAccess.Dictionaries.ReferenceDataDictionary`2.Get(TKey key, LookupStrategy strategy)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Pipelines.EnsureSessionContext.EnsureDevice.LoadDevice(Guid deviceId)



Nested Exception



Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'DeviceProfilesController
```

Comment: Please describe your environment. CD/CM or stand alone?

Comment: This is Standalone environment, Thanks

Comment: can you check xconnect logs, for me looks like xconnect was not installed correctly

Comment: Unfortunately this sounds like a normal misconfigured xConnect. Please review these questions: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8561/xconnect-the-http-response-was-not-successful-unauthorized, https://sitecorecompetencies.com/2019/03/27/incompatibilities-of-xconnect-and-client-certificates/