# XConnect Error While Sending The Request

Tags: xconnect

I have installed a clean version of Sitecore XP0 of my local development machine and the logs are showing the following error:

```
ManagedPoolThread #14 14:21:35 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
49008 14:21:44 ERROR Exception when executing agent aggregation/pathAnalyzerHistoryAgent
Exception: Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
Message: An error occurred while sending the request.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.Synchronous.SynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock[TResult](Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectSynchronousExtensions.SuspendContextLock(Func`1 taskFactory)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.Initialize(XmlNode configNode)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert, IFactoryHelper helper)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.Configuration.DefaultFactory.CreateObject(String configPath, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.Configuration.SitecoreXConnectClientConfiguration.GetClient(String clientConfigPath)
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Aggregation.XConnect.DefaultXdbContextFactory.CreateReadOnly()
   at Sitecore.PathAnalyzer.Processing.Agents.TreeAggregatorAgent.Execute()
   at Sitecore.Analytics.Core.BackgroundService.Run()

Nested Exception

Exception: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.ConnectionTimeoutException
Message: A task was canceled.
Source: Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteGetAsync>d__36.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.<Refresh>d__6.MoveNext()

Nested Exception

Exception: System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException
Message: A task was canceled.
Source: mscorlib
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.Xdb.Common.Web.CommonWebApiClient`1.<ExecuteAsync>d__41.MoveNext()
```

There are no errors in the XConnect logs or Event logs, so I am at a loss on how to diagnose the problem.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you check these? https://robearlam.com/blog/sitecore-xconnect-xdbcollectionunavailableexception-urgh
https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8561/xconnect-the-http-response-was-not-successful-unauthorized

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had xConnect connectivity issues after installing a clean version of Sitecore 10.2 recently on a local dev server. In my case, I had to `Disable TLS 1.3 over TCP` in IIS:

Hope this helps!

[image]

Comment: I am now getting the Forbidden error. One problem to the next

Comment: I have had success with the following answer before: https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/a/10033/3853

It basically boils down to the following: 

1) Check that the Sitecore instance application pool has read access on the xConnect client cert in MMC 

2) Check that the xConnect site in IIS has a cert selected in the HTTPS binding

3) Untrusted certificates in your root authority, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26247462/http-error-403-16-client-certificate-trust-issue

Comment: Thanks, my problem came down to certs in the wrong location.