# xConnect giving Error Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException : The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized

Tags: xconnect

I am currently endeavouring to develop an application for data extraction via XConnect. Regrettably, an error is impeding progress at the "await cfg.InitializeAsync();" segment of the code.
After reviewing the content available at [xConnect The HTTP response was not successful: Unauthorized](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/8561/xconnect-the-http-response-was-not-successful-unauthorized)
I have determined that the issue discussed does not align with the specific challenge I am currently encountering.

Below, the exception stack is provided for further review and analysis.

```
Sitecore.XConnect.XdbCollectionUnavailableException
  HResult=0x80131500
  Message=An error occurred while sending the request.
  Source=Sitecore.XConnect.Client
  StackTrace:
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient.<Refresh>d__6.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Sitecore.XConnect.Client.XConnectClientConfiguration.<InitializeAsync>d__32.MoveNext()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Sitecore.TechnicalMarketing.xConnectTutorial.Program.<MainAsync>d__1.MoveNext() in C:\Users\26384\source\repos\SitecoreDataExtraction\XConnectTutorial\xConnectTutorial\Program.cs:line 42
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at Sitecore.TechnicalMarketing.xConnectTutorial.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Users\26384\source\repos\SitecoreDataExtraction\XConnectTutorial\xConnectTutorial\Program.cs:line 20

  This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    [External Code]

Inner Exception 1:
HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.

Inner Exception 2:
WebException: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a receive.

Inner Exception 3:
Win32Exception: The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized
```

I have provided only the URL of the xConnect website that is hosted on my IIS from the supplied credentials.

given below is the code for creating xConnectClientCongiguration:

```
public virtual XConnectClientConfiguration GetClientConfiguration(string collectionHost, string searchHost, string configHost, string thumbprint)
{
    //Set up the certificate used to connect to xConnect endpoints
    var options = CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifierOptions.Parse("StoreName=My;StoreLocation=LocalMachine;FindType=FindByThumbprint;FindValue=" + thumbprint);
    var certificateModifier = new CertificateHttpClientHandlerModifier(options);

    //Set up timeout modifier for the client
    var timeoutClientModifier = new TimeoutHttpClientModifier(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 20));
    var clientModifiers = new List<IHttpClientModifier>
    {
        timeoutClientModifier
    };

//Initialize the clients. Each requires the certificate in order to open the connection
    var collectionClient = new CollectionWebApiClient(new Uri(collectionHost + "/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
     var searchClient = new SearchWebApiClient(new Uri(searchHost + "/odata"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });
    var configurationClient = new ConfigurationWebApiClient(new Uri(configHost + "/configuration"), clientModifiers, new[] { certificateModifier });

//Create the configuration object with all clients
var cfg = new XConnectClientConfiguration(
                new XdbRuntimeModel(CollectionModel.Model), collectionClient, searchClient, configurationClient);

 //Test configuration
 var outputHandler = new OutputHandler();
 try
 {
    await cfg.InitializeAsync();

    // Print xConnect validation message if configuration is valid
    outputHandler.WriteValidationMessage();
 }
 catch (XdbModelConflictException ce)
 {
    outputHandler.WriteError("Error initializing configuration", ce);
    return;
 }
}
```

I am getting error on

```
await cfg.InitializeAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check you are running in an admin mode and following app pools are assigned to the XConnect certificate.

- Service
- IUSR
- Network Service
- IIS_IUSRS
- Local Service

[image]

Once the app pool roles assigned to the certificate, restart the app-pool.
Hope this helps!!!